# My windows application is showing black and white emojis in Text Edit Box?

Tags: windows, controls, emoji, richedit, richeditbox

I have created a Text Edit Box using Microsoft RichEdit Controls. But I am having black and white Emojis. Using Windows msftedit.dll library and RichEdit50W windows class.

- Windows 11
- I have tried installing Segoe Font and Emojis

Please help me in how I can set the appropriate coloured emojis support.

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the RichEdit developers, you must [use RichEdit in Direct2D mode](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/math-in-office/richeditd2d-window-controls/) and this only exists in the RichEdit shipped with Office.

> The Windows 11 Notepad uses the RichEditD2DPT window class with a recent Microsoft 365 RichEdit. On my laptop, the Microsoft 365 RichEdit is housed in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16\riched20.dll.

Then send it `EM_SWITCHTOD2D` (WM_USER + 389) before adding text.

Comment: I am able to colorise the emojis using above mentions .dll. Do we have something in msftedit.dll for the same?

Comment: What was unclear? Msftedit does not support direct2d nor color emoji. Only office library does.

Comment: In the end of the article Sargent suggested a way to implement ITextService to provide the coloured functionality but I have tried using it. But enable to use it properly. In my application. I don't have the flexibility to use RichEdit shipped with office. So I have to use msftedit.dll. Please help me how can I use ITextService or ITextHost for this purpose.